# Having Issue Deploying A Flask App on ElasticBean Stalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Flask Application requires the package cryptography==2.2.2. I included this in the requirements.txt.

But when deployed onto AWS, I get the error

> File "/var/app/build/cryptography/setup.py", line 28, in
>
> "cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a "
>
> RuntimeError: cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please
>   upgrade to a newer version of setuptools

I tried fixing it by creating a config file - 01_upgrade_pip.config

```
01_upgrade_pip.config
   commands:
      pip_upgrade:
          command: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
          ignoreErrors: false
```

My solution did not work, can anyone help? Thank you!

**Edit V1**
I have found a solution to the problem discussed about, but I ran into another problem.

For those interested, I was using Python 3.4 running on 64Bit Debian/2.10.0. I later switched the configuration to Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.0 and it seemed to resolve the issue.

The problem I have right now is I am getting this error:

> File "/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip", line 4, in  import re
>   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/re.py", line 142, in
>    class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag): AttributeError: module 'enum'
>   has no attribute 'IntFlag' 2018-05-30 13:40:55,527 ERROR Error
>   installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install
>   -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1

I have tried uninstalling enum34, and I still got the same result. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had to rebuild the environment and restart the server.

Comment: rebuild means redeploy or make a different env itself @cruise_lab

Comment: rebuild means make a different env itself

Comment: I am struck at the same problem.. How does rebuilding the env helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058916/error-occurred-during-build-command-setuptools-failed