# Error occurred during build: Command setuptools failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, setuptools

I am trying to deploy an application on AWS but struck at this error and couldn't find how to make it work.

Error:

> Error occurred during build: Command setuptools failed

**01_packages.config**

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql-devel: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []

commands:
    setuptools:
      command: /opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

I guess there's been change in AWS Recently as this was working in my previous deployments.

Also I had to change

```
postgresql93-devel: []
```

to

```
postgresql-devel: []
```

Because it was earlier giving the following error:

> Yum does not have postgresql93-devel available for installation

db-migrate.congig

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: app_name.settings
```

django.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: yantraksh_cargo/wsgi.py
```

wsgi_custom.config

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgihacks.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fails because file `/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip` **does not exist**. Not at least on Amazon Linux 2 (python env).

To fixed that, you can use

```
commands:
    setuptools:
      command: pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

To check if it works, I **verified** it on a test EB env (`64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.0.1 running Python 3.7`):

```
2020-05-28 07:47:14,369 P3704 [INFO] Command setuptools
2020-05-28 07:47:16,759 P3704 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2020-05-28 07:47:16,759 P3704 [INFO]    Collecting setuptools
2020-05-28 07:47:16,759 P3704 [INFO]      Downloading setuptools-46.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (583 kB)
2020-05-28 07:47:16,759 P3704 [INFO]    Installing collected packages: setuptools
2020-05-28 07:47:16,759 P3704 [INFO]      Attempting uninstall: setuptools
2020-05-28 07:47:16,759 P3704 [INFO]        Found existing installation: setuptools 38.4.0
2020-05-28 07:47:16,759 P3704 [INFO]        Uninstalling setuptools-38.4.0:
2020-05-28 07:47:16,760 P3704 [INFO]          Successfully uninstalled setuptools-38.4.0
2020-05-28 07:47:16,760 P3704 [INFO]    Successfully installed setuptools-46.4.0
```

EDIT:

General migration steps from Amazon Linux 1 to 2 are outline here:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Comment: But I have deployed 2 other apps in the past using the same command.. it has never shown that error before

Comment: @RahulSharma Maybe you used Amazon Linux 1?

Comment: Yes, you are right!! I just checked the version and it was "Amazon Linux" only, although the deployment is now stuck at "Error occurred during build: Command 01_migrate failed" Can you please help with it too ? I have shared all the ebextension files

Comment: @RahulSharma There are many breaking changes between AL1 and AL2. AWS has written a [migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html). It should be helpful.

Comment: @RahulSharma I updated answer with the link. For the new issue, I don't why it failed. You would have to provide error messages from logs. If you have the logs, you can make new question if you want, with specific details related to the new problem.